# Преобразовать список сессий во временной ряд

Tags: алгоритм

Есть сырые данные истории использования объектов в виде списка сесстй-троек `(id объекта, время начала, время окончания)`

```
[(1, "2012-09-20 00:00:00+04", "2012-09-20 05:00:00+04"),
 (1, "2012-09-20 07:30:00+04", "2012-09-20 09:25:00+04"),
 (2, "2012-09-20 07:00:00+04", "2012-09-20 09:15:00+04")]
```

Т.е., в данном примере объект 1 использовался дважды, с 00:00 по 05:00 и с 07:30 по 09:25, а объект 2 — с 07:00 по 09:15. Список сейчас отсортирован по ID объекта и потом по возрастающему времени, но можно подать данные в любом виде — в общем-то, это таблица в SQL'ной RDBMS.

Записи как правило, не должны, но, теоретически, могут пересекаться — т.е., может случиться так, что будет `[(1, "…", "… 12:00:37"), (1, "… 11:59:42", "…")]`, и в этом случае можно считать, что использование в районе 12 часов не прерывалось.

Хочу получить из такого списка временной ряд, условно, следующего вида:

```
[("2012-09-20 00:00:00+04", {1}),
 ("2012-09-20 05:00:00+04", {}),
 ("2012-09-20 07:00:00+04", {2}),
 ("2012-09-20 07:30:00+04", {1,2}),
 ("2012-09-20 09:15:00+04", {1}),
 ("2012-09-20 09:25:00+04", {})]
```

Т.е. с 00:00 (минимальная дата-время в истории) использовался объект 1, потом в 05:00 ничего, потом с 07:00 — объект 2, затем оба объекта, и т.д., до 09:25, на которое данные закончились.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, хороший алгоритм и структуры данных для быстрого выполнения такого преобразования. Объемы — до 10000 объектов, за сроки различной продолжительности (сутки, неделя, месяц, 3 месяца, 6 месяцев, год, больше не интересно), до 100000 записей в сутки.

Процессорного времени жалко, памяти — сколько угодно, в физически разумных пределах.

Очевидный «жадный» алгоритм с пробегом по временному интервалу не годится — алгоритм не должен напрямую зависеть от продолжительности рассматриваемого интервала, только от количества записей в истории.

Comment: судя по количеству записей в сутки, их будет больше чем секунд в сутках, пробег по временному интервалу выглядит не таким уж плохим.

Comment: Это в пике, если вдруг систему начало «дергать» и та стала активно завершать и тут же снова начинать сессии. Обычный порядок — что-то между 5000—10000 записей/сутки.

Comment: Такое ощущение, что результата можно добиться запросом. Надо подумать, повертеть. От пересечения интервалов для одного объекта по крайней мере точно можно избавиться.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- В такой формулировке, если я правильно все интерпретировал, то звучит как типичный `use case` для структуры данных под названием [**Interval Tree.**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) *Алгоритм может выглядеть примерно следующим образом:*

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bjVG.png]

---

- Нестрогое обоснование и оценка сложности алгоритма:

> - Понятно, что изменение множества текущих выполняемых объектов может произойти только в момент `start` или `end` для некоторой тройки, поэтому подход с `UNIQUE` должен сработать.
> - Время работы для `n` входных элементов будет равно `O(n log n) + O(n) + O(n * (log n + k)) = O(n * (log n + k))`, где `k` - это количество элементов с пересекающимися интервалами, поскольку сложность вставки составляет `O(log n),` а стоимость запроса - `O(log n + k)`.
> - Алгоритмическую сложность операций для `Interval Tree` я подсмотрел [**здесь.**](http://3glab.cs.nthu.edu.tw/%7Espoon/courses/CS631100/Lecture05_handout.pdf)

- В свое время пользовался [`boost::icl`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/icl/doc/html/index.html) для схожих целей.

Comment: Да, похоже это (я так понял, что с метаданными оно обычно зовется interval maps?) как раз то, что нужно. По крайней мере очень похоже. Спасибо!

Comment: @drdaeman Да, но там есть [хитрые правила агрегации метаданных.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/icl/doc/html/boost_icl/semantics/maps.html) Вообще, `ICL` явно писал человек с академическим складом ума :)

Answer (score 3):

У меня такой запрос получился:

```
select l1.begindate a, group_concat(l2.obj), 1
from logs l1 join logs l2 on
l2.begindate <= l1.begindate and l2.enddate>=l1.begindate
group by a
union all
select l1.enddate a, group_concat(l2.obj), 2
from logs l1 left join logs l2 on
l2.begindate<=l1.enddate and l2.enddate>l1.enddate
group by a
order by a;
```

На пересечение интервалов не проверял...

Comment: некоторой проблемой является использование специфичной GROUP_CONCAT

Comment: она не специфичная, во многих субд есть либо аналог, либо можно добиться аналогичного функционала через процедуры...  гуглящий да обрящет.

Answer (score 2):

Ну раз указано, что это SQL-база, то она просто с этим справится
Список объектов, используемых в каждый момент времени тут заменен на их количество. Если потребуется - их тоже легко получить

```
(SELECT t1.start
      , count(*)
 FROM
   table t1
 JOIN table t2
 ON t2.start <= t1.start AND t2.finish > t1.start
 GROUP BY
   t1.start
)

UNION

(SELECT t3.finish
      , count(*)
 FROM
   table t3
 JOIN table t4
 ON t4.start <= t3.finish AND t4.finish > t3.finish
 GROUP BY
   t3.finish)

UNION

(SELECT t5.finish
     , 0
FROM
  table t5
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM
    table t6
  WHERE
    t5.finish > t6.start
    AND t5.finish < t6.finish
  )
 )

ORDER BY
  1
```

Comment: +1. отлично.